# If cell contains more than one string, put in to the new cell in Pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas

So I'm working with Pandas and I have multiple words (i.e. strings) in one cell, and I need to put every word into the new row and keep coordinated data. I've found a method which could help me,but it works with numbers, not strings.
So what method do I need to use?

Simple example of my table:

```
id name     method
1  adenosis mammography, mri
```

And I need it to be:

```
id name     method
1  adenosis mammography
            mri
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

That's what I'm trying to do, according to @jezrael's proposal:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
xl = pd.ExcelFile("./dev/eyetoai/google_form_pure.xlsx")
xl.sheet_names
df = xl.parse("Form Responses 1")
df.groupby(['Name of condition','Condition description','Relevant Modality','Type of finding Mammography', 'Type of finding MRI', 'Type of finding US']).mean()
splitted = df['Relevant Modality'].str.split(',')
l = splitted.str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat(df[col], l) for col in ['Name of condition','Condition description']})
df['Relevant Modality'] = np.concatenate(splitted)
```

But I have this type of error: 
TypeError: repeat() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Do you need no values in first and second column? Or it is multiindex?

Comment: No values is totally fine yet, I don't see any necessity to add them right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) + [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) + [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
#define columns which need split by , and then flatten them
cols = ['Condition description','Relevant Modality']

#read csv to dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('Untitled 1.xlsx')
#print (df)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].str.split(',', expand=True).stack() for col in cols})
print (df1)
                                 Condition description Relevant Modality
0 0  Fibroadenomas are the most common cause of a b...       Mammography
  1                                                NaN                US
  2                                                NaN               MRI
1 0                    Papillomas are benign neoplasms       Mammography
  1                                  arising in a duct                US
  2   either centrally or peripherally within the b...               MRI
  3   leading to a nipple discharge. As they are of...               NaN
  4                 the discharge may be bloodstained.               NaN
2 0                                                 OK       Mammography
3 0                                      breast cancer       Mammography
  1                                                NaN                US
4 0                                breast inflammation       Mammography
  1                                                NaN                US

#remove original columns
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
#create Multiindex in original df for align rows
df.index = [df.index, [0]* len(df.index)]
#join original to flattened columns, remove Multiindex
df = df1.join(df).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)
```

Comment: That's what I have when I'm trying to use this method: "TypeError: repeat() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)". Can you maybe explain more on that?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Maybe that's because I am working with *.xlsx file?

Comment: I think if read excel to `DataFrame`, there is no problem. This should works.

Comment: It seems assign is missing `df = df.groupby(['Name of condition','Condition description','Relevant Modality','Type of finding Mammography', 'Type of finding MRI', 'Type of finding US']).mean().reset_index()`

Comment: Take a look on update, I tried to paste code here but it's not formatted.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, can you share your file, best anonymize, 5 rows of data? There hast to be something wrong.

Comment: I think yes, thanks for your help! Sending you an email.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I check it, no email yet

Comment: Just sent with "StackOverflow help" subject. Thanks!

Comment: YES YES YES THANKS!

Comment: And please check it ;)

Comment: Super Alice, glad can help ;)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct, I think you should use the id of reference.
an easier way could possibly be to just parse the method string to a list:

```
method_list = method.split(',')
method_list = np.asarray(method_list)
```

If you have any trouble with indexing when initializing your Dataframe, just set index to:

```
pd.Dataframe(data, index=[0,0])
df.set_index('id')
```

passing the list as a value for your method key will automatically create a copy of both the index - 'id' and 'name'

```
id       method      name
1   mammography  adenosis
1           mri  adenosis
```

I hope this helps, all the best

Comment: Thanks, sorry may sound like a dumb syntax question - if my column name is not 'method', but 'method of diagnostics', how should I refer to it?

Comment: to refer to the data Series you would use, `df['method of diagnostics']`